# System.StackOverflow exception from recursive dependency between classes

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am using the repository pattern with a service layer in my application. To follow best practices I am creating a service for each repo.

Two of my services are dependent on one another. I need to call at least one method from each, from the other service.

I am using dependency injection to resolves these dependencies. It seems that the problem stems from the following:

- Class A is dependent on Class B
- Class B is dependent on Class A

my DI container resolves all of the above.

I make a call to Class A and an instance of class B get injected...

This causes the container to create a new instance of class A for class B....

Which in turn injects a new Class A for Class B...and so on...

I am thinking this is a basic design flaw on my part but I see no obvious way to get around this.

Any ideas?

**Example**

```
public UserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepo;
    private readonly ITransactionService transactionService;

    //ctor here....

    public ExampleUserMethod()
    {
         transactionService.GetTransactions();
         //do other things
    }

    public GetUsers()
    {
        //return users
    }


}

public TransactionService
{
    private readonly ITransactionRepository transactionRepo;
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    //ctor here....

    public ExampleTransactionMethod()
    {
         userService.GetUsers();
         //Do other things...
    }


    public GetTransactions()
    {
        //return transactions
    }

}
```

Comment: With no code shown, there is nothing to fix. Best of luck! Oh, to blurt out the obvious: the timing of the instance creation is too tight. Instantiation of the 'other' container should at least be lazy enough to not trigger an infinite loop. Like I said, _with_ code could be more helpful

Comment: sounds like a bad design.  One thing DI will do for you is enforce some better designs.  Like the others said, need some code examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can dependency injection prevent a circular dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053044/can-dependency-injection-prevent-a-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some containers support circular references if they have a lifetime. This way A if A ir requested it is created first and added to the cache. Then B is created because it is required as dependency and assigned to A. Because B requires an instance of A an A is requested but not created again because it is found in the cache and this existing instance is assigned.

But I suggest not to use this solution. You better try to break the circular reference first. Circular references are never a good idea. E.g. taking your example:

```
public UserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepo;
    private readonly ITransactionStore transactionStore;

    //ctor here....

    public ExampleUserMethod()
    {
         transactionStore.GetTransactions();
         //do other things
    }

    public GetUsers()
    {
        //return users
    }


}

public TransactionService
{
    private readonly ITransactionStore transactionStore;
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    //ctor here....

    public ExampleTransactionMethod()
    {
         userService.GetUsers();
         //Do other things...
         transactionStore.AddTransaction(transaction);
    }
}

public class TransactionStore
{
    private readonly ITransactionRepository transactionRepo;

    public GetTransactions()
    {
        //return transactions
    }

    public AddTransaction()
    {
        //return transactions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having few knowledge about DI, from my understanding, it doesn't matter with which technology you model a circular dependency; it is always wrong to do so, no matter how it is implemented.

If you use no DI, your compiler would have notified you; now since you are relocating it to the runtime, the error occurs later and the runtime notifies you.

So my suggestion is to remove this circular dependency.

Comment: The compiler is not going to warn of such dependencies between classes. `class Foo { Bar bar; } class Bar { Foo foo; }` is perfectly fine as far as the compiler goes.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I read "depends" as "derives from" (i.e. "is a", not "has a"). Is this a false assumption?

Comment: I would say very false on the assumption. When talking dependencies, particularly in the context of DI, we're talking about composition, not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to get around this to me seems to move all the things both class A and B need to class C, and let class A and B both refer to (or get injected with) class C

but without a concrete example of what you're trying to do, its hard to say