# Is it possible to statically access the current controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Out of pure curiosity, is it possible to access the current controller from a static context while it is being executed with the current `HttpRequest`/Action?

Comment: I'd suggest summarizing your comments on used2could's answer in your question, it's helpful to have some context other than "curiosity" :)

Comment: @Daniel - Understood :) But if you follow those links, they're the exact context I was talking about. I figured this wasn't even possible since there can obviously be many controllers executing at any point, but I just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible from a static context because many different controllers could be executing at some given point of time for multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: I figured as much - I just wasn't sure if there was some special way to do this. Regardless, I realized my design was flawed and reworked it so that I don't need this requirement. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it statically but what I do for this while handling some session/authentication management I have all my controllers inherit from a custom BaseController class that inherits from the System.Web.Mvc.Controller class. In the Base Controller class I override the OnActionExecuted method.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Your logic here

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}


public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm making a wrapper for `ModelStateDictionary` and I'm trying to inject the "current controller" inside of it so that the controller's `ModelState` property can be used inside of a service, so this won't do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873530/inject-asp-net-mvc-controller-property-into-service-layer-dependency and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077055/ioc-on-ivalidationdictionary-with-castle-windsor for more detail :)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Good luck mate!