# Dependency-Injection to resolve circular dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, refactoring, inversion-of-control

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    Composition m_Composition;

    void MyClass()
    {
        m_Composition = new Composition( this );
    }
}
```

I am interested in using depenency-injection here. So I will have to refactor the constructor to something like:

```
void MyClass( Composition composition )
{
    m_Composition = composition;
}
```

However I get a problem now, since the `Composition`-object relies on the object of type `MyClass` which is just created.

*Can a dependency container resolve this?* Is it supposed to do so?
*Or is it just bad design from the beginning on?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**, a DI Container will not solve a **circular dependency** - in fact, it will protest against it by throwing exceptions when you try to resolve the dependencies.

In many of the DI Containers you can provide advanced configuration that allows you to overcome this issue, but by themselves they can't resolve circular dependencies. How could they?

As a rule of thumb, a circular depedency is a **design smell**. If you can, consider an alternative design where you get rid of the circular dependency - this will also give you **less coupling**. Some possible redesign alternatives:

- Use **events** to signal from one class to another. Often a circular dependency already mostly goes in one direction, and when this is the case, modeling part of this signaling API as events may cut the circle.
- If the above is true, but you feel that events seem wrong, you can consider applying the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.
- If the communication must truly go both ways, you can use a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) through which the components can communicate.

However, I purposedly chose the word *smell* over *anti-pattern*, as there are corner cases (particularly when you deal with externally defined APIs) where circular dependencies cannot be avoided.

In such cases, you need to decide where to loosen the dependency creation slightly. Once you know that, injection of an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) may be helpful to defer one of the creations until the other parts of the circle have been created.

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453128/is-there-a-good-proper-way-of-solving-the-dependency-injection-loop-problem-in-th/1453242#1453242) is the best, available example of which I'm currently aware, but if I may be so bold, my upcoming book will also contain a section that addresses this very issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to find out if I can avoid the circular reference in my case, though I am not sure, yet: I need the reference to subscribe to some events of MyClass within Composition's constructor ... Thanks for mentioning your book, which sounds very interesting. I am looking forward to read it.

Comment: To be clear: although you can already buy early access to the book, the section about dealing with circular references is not yet available.

Comment: It seems to me that the way you've described it, using events, Observer or Mediator patterns in this situation are hacks to get around the circular dependency. If, coupling is bad, as you say, and dependencies (even acyclic ones) cause coupling, why not do away with dependencies altogether and just use Observer or Mediator patterns at the outset?

Comment: @poshest I'm not sure I follow... If you consider Observer or Mediator hacks (which I don't), then how does using them 'at the outset' change that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann sorry, I'm not saying they're hacks per se, but they become hacks when used _solely_ as a method for busting a circular dependency.